# Subclassing QObject and Q_OBJECT macro

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

In C++ code, do inherited signals\slots and internal Qt tracking work on a class inherited from QObject but not sporting Q_OBJECT macro in definition, or use of such and of MOC utility is mandatory?

Comment: If you are not going to use signals/slots in your Qt sub classes, `Q_OBJECT` is not needed.

Comment: @vahancho Not quite true, you still need the macro if you want the object to be used in the meta-object system. That includes stuff like `qobject_cast`. It is really discouraged to omit the macro! [See last sentence here.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html)

Comment: @dave so it's their RTTI system and signals\slots.  What about tracking system, they don't even mentioned it there. E.g. if parent dies, child dies too (that's only part I use. The RTTI part actually wouldn't be safe to use in my case anyway because multiple threads involved. I'm revising code that used a bunch of objects  derived from QObject, but in legacy state they weren't (e.g. QThread of Qt 3.5). Including MOC steps within preexisting build chain (which didn't use QMake) that involves literally a hundred of files and several dozens of projects is task out of my time frame.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I think children being deleted still works, because they just keep a list of pointers and call `delete` on them, so it relies on the standard c++ vtables. [At least that's what I'm seeing here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L2048)